# how to extract a widget that has an onPressed method after upgrading flutter to be Flutter 2.0.4

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-upgrade

in the past when I used to extract widgets that have a button and onPressed method in it

I used to replace the callback function that the **onPressed method** takes with a variable with a **Function data type**

but now when I try to extract a widget that I called **RoundedButton**
after upgrading the **flutter version to 2.0.4** which is the latest stable version of flutter.

it gives me that error:

*`**The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.**`*

and this is the code with a red line under the `onPressed: onPressed,` line of code:

```
class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  final Function onPressed;

  RoundedButton(
      {required this.onPressed, required this.color, required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: Material(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
        elevation: 5.0,
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 42.0,
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of the old type of it which was: `

> Function

I figured out the type of onPressed method used in flutter 2.0.4

it's `

> VoidCallback?

with importing the `**dart:io**` library

Answer (score 0):

use
final VoidCallback onPressed;
//final void Function() onPressed;